# Can't seem to find the line that's causing the error

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing Angular into my React app using [this](https://github.com/fmauquie/react-angular) library, but when I run my application I get this error. [image] I know this error has to do with the below code, but am unsure on how to fix it. [image]

```
import React from 'react';
import AngularTemplate from 'react-angular';
import Template from './template.jsx';

export default function Profile(props) {
  return(
    <AngularTemplate
      template={Template}
      inject={props}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: What's in template.jsx? Also turn on source maps with webpack to get meaningful stack traces

Comment: The jsx I want to render, it is way to long to put in the question. How would I turn on source maps?

Comment: Are you sure you have react installed? Check node_modules and make sure React is there.

Comment: yes, I can load my whole application just not this page....